# При SSE подключении сервер падает. Требуется полная перезагрузка

Tags: php, nginx, docker, apache2, server-side-events

Создается постоянное подключение с PHP-Apache2 сервером с использованием [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventSource). На самом сервере скрипт подключается к RabbitMQ событиям, что дает моментальное обновление данных у клиента.

Эта связка работает замечательно. Но только у меня на компьютере. В действительности же на сервере происходит вот что:

- Клиент подключается к серверу, и вроде как все хорошо. Сервер отправляет обновления и все счастливы. Пока.
- Со временем соединение сбрасывается с ошибкой в консоли `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` (что бы это не значило)
- Клиент переподключается автоматически (так работает SSE). Каждый раз. Пока сервер не станет выдавать ошибку 50*

[image: ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR]

Перезагрузка контейнеров не помогает. Некоторые контейнеры становятся неубиваемые (docker stop и docker kill не помогают), из-за чего приходится полностью перезапускать сервер. В некоторых самых печальных случаях меня даже по SSH не пускает.

Что имеется:

- Самый последний Docker + Docker Compose
- Nginx proxy + Letsencrypt. Конфигурация с небольшими изменениями взята [здесь](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion)
- Мои [docker-compose.common.yml](https://pastebin.com/XVJTwSeK) и [docker-compose.prod.yml](https://pastebin.com/UwRny6QD)
- Виртуальный сервер: Intel® Xeon™ 1 Core, 20 GB SSD, 1 GB DDR4, KVM

У меня на ПК с 8ГБ ОЗУ все работает идеально. Соединение постоянное, не прерывается, ошибок нет. Возможно, где-то утечка памяти и либо oomkiller убивает процесс за прожорливость, либо процесс убивается сам. Но это вряд-ли объясняет ошибку `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. И вроде как Apache2 сам достаточно умен, чтобы держать под контролем память.

В системном администрировании я не специализируюсь (скорее любитель, чем профессионал), поэтому мог упустить какие-то важные моменты. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в моей логике, разобраться, откуда берется `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` и почему падает сервер.

**UPDATE:**

После долгого подключения с чередой переподключений сервер упал с ожидаемой ошибкой 502:

[image: 502]

Видимо что-то происходит в это время с Apache.

Подключиться по SSH все же удалось, но Docker почти совсем не живой. На обычные команды он не реагировал, перезапустить методом `service docker stop|start` не удается... Даже `docker-composer logs` не запускается

Не совсем понимаю, как связан Apache и Docker. В том плане, почему проблемы внутри апача должны как-то негативно влиять на работу демона Docker? Или проблема глубже?

Я в легком отчаянии.

**UPDATE 2:**

Нашел вот [эту статью](https://ma.ttias.be/nginx-spdy-error-neterr_spdy_protocol_error/), которая ведет на [эту статью](https://ma.ttias.be/enable-spdy-in-nginx-on-centos-6/), которая предлагает [на этом сайте](https://spdycheck.org/) проверить свой SPDY. Результат: Does Not Support SPDY. Все показатели зеленые или голубые. Но один выглядит вот так:

[image: SPDY Protocol Not Enabled!]

Залез внутрь моего NGINX, который в свою очередь официальный docker пакет:

```
root@s052d7f6a:/# docker exec -it nginx-web bash
root@29f7289c6a29:/# nginx -V 
nginx version: nginx/1.13.7
built by gcc 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.13.7/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.13.7=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-sec
```

Про `--with-http_spdy_module` ни слова. Думаю, это и является причиной `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. Пока не знаю, как это можно исправить. Но думаю, что не это является причиной падения сервера.

**UPDATE 3**

Как оказалось, проблема `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` происходит из-за timeout соединения в nginx proxy. Не очень очевидно со стороны Chrome.

Это выяснилось, когда я попытался подключиться к скрипту с использованием curl + time:

```
time curl my-site.com/sse.php
```

Соединение прерывалось ~ через минуту. Чуть больше, не меньше. Видимо где-то стоит timeout. В итоге нашел [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630509/server-sent-events-connection-timeout-on-node-js-via-nginx) и [эту статью](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0+504+Gateway+Time-out+%D0%B2+Nginx). Прибавление времени proxy_read_timeout до часа исправило эту проблему. Возможно. По крайней мере соединение не прерывается. Пока что жду очередного падения, чтобы что-нибудь выяснить.